# Download docx as blob

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I send a docx from backend with express:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname+"/output.docx")
}
```

I call it and download it as a blob from angular with:

```
 $http({
   url: '/api_cv/cv/gen',
   method: "PUT",
   responseType: 'blob'
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
   var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' });
   var fileName = headers('content-disposition');
   saveAs(blob, 'file.docx');
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('Unable to download the file')
});
```

It works in Chrome and firefox. In safari a new tab opens, no file is downloaded. In IE (tested via Azure RemoteApp since I have a mac), I get " your current security settings do not allow this file to be downloaded".

```
SaveAs is from https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/
```

Is there an alternate way of doing thins that works in all modern browsers and IE10+?

Comment: Have you tried using `arraybuffer` instead of `blob` as the `responseType`? Also might want to check you have access to the headers, I know that sometimes you have to explicitly allow access with `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

Comment: Tried it. Same result.

Comment: Hmm... out of interest, what does the `saveAs` function do? I was doing something very similar yesterday, saving xlsx as a `blob` and it worked fine, albeit in Chrome.

Comment: It saves the file. https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Ah right, wasn't sure if it was something you had written yourself.

Comment: FileSaver is good for client side generated files - since you are using a server, can you not just use that? ...with `content-disposition` header. It works for more browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `saveAs`, could you try the following:

```
var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var downloadUrl = url.createObjectURL(blob);

var a = doc.createElement("a");
a.style.display = "none";

if (typeof a.download === "undefined") {
   window.location = downloadUrl;
} else {
   a.href = downloadUrl;
   a.download = fileName;
   doc.body.appendChild(a);
   a.click();
}
```

And then removing the anchor when you're finished with it. Just wondering if it's the saving part that is the issue, I don't have much experience with FileSaver, but this is what I've done in the past

Comment: This is exactly what FileSaver dose internally - with other fallback solution to say like IE10 that has `navigator.saveOrOpenBlob()` for example